# Can't terminate thread with Ctrl-c

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've created a setInterval like function in python but cntrl-c can't terminate it Heres the code

```
import threading
def setInterval(sec,func,*args,**kw):
    def wrapper():
        setInterval(sec,func,*args,**kw) 
        func(*args,**kw) 
    t = threading.Timer(sec, wrapper)
    t.start()
    return t
```

And here's what I do to run it

```
>>> setInterval(3,print,"hello")
<Timer(Thread-1, started 6576)>
>>> hello
KeyboardInterrupt
>>> hello
```

It continues to run after I've hit ctrl-c. How would I add something to have it stop if I use the keyboard interupt?

Comment: You might want to add in your original post which OS you are using (and though probably not as relevant, what version of Python)

Comment: @Levon Windows 8.1 Python version 3.3 running it in python shell

Comment: Signals (including KeyboardInterrupt) are always delivered to the main thread in Python, regardless of platform.  That's why your thread doesn't see it.  Can't be changed.

Comment: If you want to kill it, full-stop, when your main thread exits, make it a daemon thread.  Otherwise if you need to do cleanup, Things Get Complicated.

Comment: The other comments are spot-on. The meaning is that python shell is not a good envirnment for testing thread-related logic. Write a test-scrtipt and run it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an [Event](http://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#event-objects) to stop the thread programmatically:

```
import time
import threading

def setInterval(sec,func,*args,**kw):
    e = threading.Event()
    def wrapper():
        print('Started')
        while not e.wait(sec):
            func(*args,**kw)
        print('Stopped')
    t = threading.Thread(target=wrapper)
    t.start()
    return t,e

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        t,e = setInterval(1,print,'hello')
        time.sleep(5)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
    e.set()
    t.join()
    print('Exiting')
```

Output:

```
Started
hello
hello
hello
hello
Stopped
Exiting
```

Hitting Ctrl-C:

```
Started
hello
hello
Stopped
Exiting
```